# Alternative for .env file for hosted Node.js application

Tags: node.js, jenkins, environment-variables

I try to find a way to get rid of `.env` file from dev, stage and prod environments for Node.js application.

The current solution which I have seems to be a little bit factitious. During the build process, in pipeline env variables are rewrite from Jenkins (Config File Provider) into new `.env` file which is attached to an application. The deployed application in run by `pm2`.

I wonder if is it a better approach to run `${envlist} pm2 start app`?

Answer (score 1):

this is just an option that I use for handling the deployment. In my projects, I always have a file **ecosystem.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        name: "my little project",
        script: "./app.js",
        instances: "max",
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: "production",
        },
        env_development: {
            NODE_ENV: "development",
        },
        env_production: {
            NODE_ENV: "production",
        }
    }]
}
```

in my entry point I have  (**app.js**):

```
if (process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE === '0' || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    // start cronJobs here or any action needs to be done in single proccess

}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') server.listen(800 + process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE);
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') server.listen(700 + process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE);
else
    server.listen(3045, err => {
        console.log(err ? err : `REST server started on 3045.`);
 
    });
```

and in your jenkins file :

```
stage('Deploy') {      
      environment {
        NODE_ENV = "production"
      }
      steps {
        sh 'pm2 start ecosystem.config.js'
      }
    }
```

you can run your app with any env you want:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

Comment: OK, but `ecosystem.config.js` is kept under version control, right? I would prefer some way not to keep any file with env variables apart from file on Jenkins.

Comment: @LancerX I cannot understand your needs. pls explain more

Comment: You could use https://www.doppler.com/